# How to remove the first two BR tags with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I'd like to remove only the first two BR tags with jquery.

```
<div id="system">
<BR CLEAR="ALL"><BR>// I want to remove both BR.
...

<BR>...
...
<BR>
```

I assume something like this. But I am not sure.

```
$('#system br').remove();
```

Could anyone tell me how to do this please?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`:lt()`](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/):

```
$('#system br:lt(2)').remove();
```

`:lt()` takes a zero-based integer as its parameter, so 2 refers to the 3rd element.  So `:lt(2)` is select elements "less than" the 3rd.

**Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3PJ5D/**

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$('#system br:first').remove();
$('#system br:first').remove();
```

The first line removes the first `br`, then the second `br` becomes the first, and then you remove the first again.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#system br:lt(2)").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Also try nth-child.

```
$("#system > br:nth-child(1), #system > br:nth-child(2)").remove();​
```

removes first and second instance of br within `#system`

Comment: Note that if there were further child elements with `<br>` elements inside them, those would be removed too.  You could work around this using the immediate child selector, `>`.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally if you only want to remove the last br only you can try;

```
$('#elementID br:last').remove();
```

Lets say that the br follows a , you can try

```
$('#elementID strong+br:last').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it. Replace (max 4 BR) to (1 BR)

```
$('#system br').each(function() {
    if ($(this).next().is('br')) {
        $(this).next().remove();
    }
});
```

[KS FIDDLE](http://www.kangsigit.com/p/editor.html?filename=remove_br)