# How to remove br using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My structure is like this:

```html
<p>something</p>
<br/>
<br/>
<p>ssddfgdfg</p>
<br/>
<br/>
<p>dsdfsfsdfsdfsd</p>
<br/>
<br/>
```

I want to remove one `br tag` whenever 2 `br tag` comes together, like this:

```html
<p>something</p>
<br/>
<p>ssddfgdfg</p>
<br/>
<p>dsdfsfsdfsdfsd</p>
<br/>
```

How can I achieve this using jQuery?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667904/how-to-remove-the-first-two-br-tags-with-jquery

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the immediate sibling selector

http://jsfiddle.net/u2vS6/

```
$('br + br').remove();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try doing

```
$('br').next('br').remove();
```

This will remove the second `<br/>`. There might be a better solution though.

EDIT: As I said other answers were better :)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution,

```
$('br').prev('br').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code

```
 $('br').each(function () 
    {
      if ($(this).next().is('br')) 
      {
        $(this).next().remove();
      }
    }
```