# How to remove extra whitespace at the beginning of a div using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to remove extra whitespace -creating tags (specifically br & p) from a div. The div contents could be following:

```
<div>
  <br>
  <br>
  something
  <br>
  something
</div>
```

But in other cases they can also be just fine:

```
<div>
  something
  <br>
  something
</div>
```

Solutions described at [How to remove the first two BR tags with jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667904/how-to-remove-the-first-two-br-tags-with-jquery) work if the BR count is known (e.g. always single br at the beginning). What about if BR amount at the beginning is between 0 and infinite? Also, BR's at the middle should not be removed.

Looking for something like $.trim for div's :)

Comment: I'd likely start with using JavaScript's replace method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will remove all duplicating `<br>` elements (including at the beginning) in the text block:

```
​$("div"​​​​​​).html(function(i, html) {
    return $.grep(html.split(/<br\s*\/?>/), function(part) {
        return $.trim(part) !== "";
    }).join("<br>");
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/S8qeb/

This will remove all `<br>` elements only at the beginning of the text block:

```
$("div").html(function(i, html) {
    var textFound = false;
    return $.grep(html.split(/<br\s*\/?>/), function(part, i) {
        if ($.trim(part) !== "") textFound = true;
        return textFound;
    }).join("<br>");
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/S8qeb/1/
​

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var otherContent = false;
$('#yourdiv').contents().each(function() {
    if(!otherContent) {
        if(this.tagName.toLowerCase() == "br") {
            $(this).remove();
        } else {
            otherContent = true;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: oops, you're right.. didnt read the question well.. will delete my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.trimmable > div').contents().each(function(i){
    var node = $(this),
        contents = $.trim(node.text());
    if (this.nodeName === 'BR' || contents === '') {
        node.remove();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/3TnMT/1/